Error on outputChannelCreateTx: config update generation failure: cannot define a new channel with no Consortium value with fabric 2.5
I am using fabric 2.5 image for my project
this is my configtx.yaml file
Organizations:
&OrdererOrg
Name: OrdererOrg
ID: OrdererMSP
MSPDir: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/blockchain.com/msp
Policies:
Readers:
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
Writers:
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
Admins:
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"
OrdererEndpoints:
    orderer.blockchain.com:7050
    orderer2.blockchain.com:8050
    orderer3.blockchain.com:9050

&Registry
Name: RegistryMSP
ID: RegistryMSP
MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/registry.blockchain.com/msp
Policies:
Readers:
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('RegistryMSP.admin', 'RegistryMSP.peer', 'RegistryMSP.client')"
Writers:
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('RegistryMSP.admin', 'RegistryMSP.client')"
Admins:
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('RegistryMSP.admin')"
Endorsement:
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('RegistryMSP.peer')"
AnchorPeers:
    Host: peer0.registry.blockchain.com
    Port: 7051

&Customer
Name: CustomerMSP
ID: CustomerMSP
MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/customer.blockchain.com/msp
Policies:
Readers:
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('CustomerMSP.admin', 'CustomerMSP.peer', 'CustomerMSP.client')"
Writers:
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('CustomerMSP.admin', 'CustomerMSP.client')"
Admins:
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('CustomerMSP.admin')"
Endorsement:
Type: Signature
Rule: "OR('CustomerMSP.peer')"
AnchorPeers:
    Host: peer0.customer.blockchain.com
    Port: 9051

Capabilities:
Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
V2_0: true
Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
V2_0: true
Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
V2_5: true
Application: &ApplicationDefaults
Organizations:
Policies:
Readers:
Type: ImplicitMeta
Rule: "ANY Readers"
Writers:
Type: ImplicitMeta
Rule: "ANY Writers"
Admins:
Type: ImplicitMeta
Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
LifecycleEndorsement:
Type: ImplicitMeta
Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
Endorsement:
Type: ImplicitMeta
Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
Capabilities:
<<: *ApplicationCapabilities
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
OrdererType: etcdraft
Addresses:

orderer.blockchain.com:7050
orderer2.blockchain.com:8050
orderer3.blockchain.com:9050
EtcdRaft:
Consenters:
Host: orderer.blockchain.com
Port: 7050
ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/blockchain.com/orderers/orderer.blockchain.com/tls/server.crt
ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/blockchain.com/orderers/orderer.blockchain.com/tls/server.crt
Host: orderer2.blockchain.com
Port: 8050
ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/blockchain.com/orderers/orderer2.blockchain.com/tls/server.crt
ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/blockchain.com/orderers/orderer2.blockchain.com/tls/server.crt
Host: orderer3.blockchain.com
Port: 9050
ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/blockchain.com/orderers/orderer3.blockchain.com/tls/server.crt
ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/blockchain.com/orderers/orderer3.blockchain.com/tls/server.crt
BatchTimeout: 2s
BatchSize:
MaxMessageCount: 10
AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
Organizations:
Policies:
Readers:
Type: ImplicitMeta
Rule: "ANY Readers"
Writers:
Type: ImplicitMeta
Rule: "ANY Writers"
Admins:
Type: ImplicitMeta
Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
BlockValidation:
Type: ImplicitMeta
Rule: "ANY Writers"

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
Policies:
Readers:
Type: ImplicitMeta
Rule: "ANY Readers"
Writers:
Type: ImplicitMeta
Rule: "ANY Writers"
Admins:
Type: ImplicitMeta
Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
Capabilities:
<<: *ChannelCapabilities
Profiles:
ThreeOrgsChannel:
<<: *ChannelDefaults
Orderer:
<<: *OrdererDefaults
Organizations:

*OrdererOrg
Capabilities:
<<: *OrdererCapabilities
Application:
<<: *ApplicationDefaults
Organizations:
*Registry
*Customer
Capabilities:
<<: *ApplicationCapabilities

I am getting this err
Error on outputChannelCreateTx: config update generation failure: cannot define a new channel with no Consortium value
while
configtxgen -configPath ./configtx/ -profile ThreeOrgsChannel -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/registry-channel.block
In fabric 2.5 there is feature to create channel without consortium, but i am unable to, don't know where i'm missing
I have checked all the config files
